# Testing animations angular 1.2+

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing

Anyone know how to test animations in angular? Animations built using either the $animateProvider or angular.module('', []).animate() ? I'm building an animations library, and it's nice, but I can't find a proper way to test the animations using the $animate. They never work. I have hacked it to get to work, but I'm pretty much recreating all the animations inside each test. Just to make sure it's not my animations, i created a new one on the test. I got this straight out of Angular's source code and it still does not work.

```
describe('Testing Async Animations', function() {
  var am = false;
  beforeEach(module('ngAnimate'));
  beforeEach(module('ngAnimateMock'));
  beforeEach(module(function($animateProvider){
    $animateProvider.register('.fade', function(){
      return {
        enter: function(element, done){
          console.log('here');
          am = true;
          done();
        }
      };
    });
  }));

  /* the done() method is something mocha provides.
     to make this work in Jasmine, just follow their
     example with using a asynchronous test */
  it("should asynchronously test the animation", function() {
    inject(function($animate, $compile, $document, $rootScope, $rootElement) {
      var element = $compile('<div class="fade">hello</div>')($rootScope);
      $rootElement.append(element);
      angular.element($document[0].body).append($rootElement);
      $animate.enabled(true);
      $animate.enter(element, $rootElement);
      $rootScope.$digest();
      expect(am).to.be(true);

    });
  });

});
```

Comment: "They never work". The test, or the animation? And in what way do they not work? Can you give an example animation that you're testing that doesn't work? A Plunker will be very helpful here. Also, the facts that you've copied Angular's tests, and have mentioned you're recreating the animations in the tests, suggest you might be testing the wrong thing. Angular's tests check that its API (e.g. the `enter` function) runs when it should. Your tests should verify the behaviour of what happens inside the `enter` function. Again, posting the animation code here and in a Plunker, would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was correct in the way I test the animations, however at the time Angular made a change to ngMocks in v1.2.16 which screwed everything up.